# Why can my Java code run?

Tags: java

In Java, `if` should have `{}` except when there is only one line under `if`.

But then, why can the following code run on my computer?

```
 int x=1;
 int y=1;


        if(x<=4)
            if(y>=4)
                System.out.println("%%%");
            else
                System.out.println("+++");
            System.out.println("***");
```

Here is what it looks like on my IDE:
[image]

And everything runs good. Here is the result (under it loading other resources, don't care about that. I just modified some of my code to try out the code as soon as possible.)

[image]

Comment: `System.out.println("***");` is executed every time, it's not in the `if` or `else` statement. It's just badly intended, should be at the same level as the first `if`.

Comment: one line is not correct.  one executable block of code

Comment: Please provide the source that state that rule (so we can tell you how much it is wrong)

Comment: @ortis Thanks. I should do more work next time. And during this searching process, problem solves itself.

Comment: Thanks for everyone who edited my question. There is still a long way to go!

Answer (score 3):

Java will associate the `else` to the last candidate `if`.
Your code (with braces) is equal to

```
if(x<=4) {
    if(y>=4) {
        System.out.println("%%%");
    } else {
        System.out.println("+++");
    }
}
System.out.println("***");
```

A candidate `if` is matched when there is exactly 1 statement (ending with semicolon) or block between the `if` and the `else`.

Comment: also that java executes one statement following if or an else. and not the whole line. Because in java you can write multiple statements in the same line. if else works like how braces work. if u open another brace without closing the previous brace. any new closing brace is considered for the currentmost open brace.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you all and the problem solved.

The point is, **`if` execute the next one statement or block.**
Java considers the following code as a whole statement.

```
`if(y>=4)
     System.out.println("%%%");  
 else
     System.out.println("+++");`
```

And it follows the first `if`.

The last print is not in the scope of consideration, it's just caused by bad indentation.

Answer (score -3):

This is your code

```
  if(x<=4)
    if(y>=4)
        System.out.println("%%%");
    else
        System.out.println("+++");
    System.out.println("***");
```

this is what java thinks
          if(Boolean) go to next line
            if(Boolean) ok this is false, go to else       f